# Design Refactoring

Tags: c#

I am designing a System where the following scanario arise.
I have a method f1() for which behavior varies across implementation.
I have a method f2() for which behavior is same for all implementations.

I have designed as following:

```
interface I1
{
        //Behaviour will vary across implementations 
        void f1();
        //Same behaviour for all implementations
        void f2();

 }

    abstract class C
    {
        //Implemented in the Base class
        void f2()
        {


        }
    }

    public class C1:C,I1
    {
        //Implemented interface method
        public f1()
        {

        }

    }
    public class C2:C,I1
    {
        //Implemented  interface method
        public f1()
        {

        }

    }
```

Is the design is correct? Can anybody suggest any appropriate design in this sceanario ?

Comment: Looks just swell. Of course we can't tell without context, but this would work for the descriptions in the comment...

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mhop/archive/2006/12/12/implicit-and-explicit-interface-implementations.aspx   Check this link out. I think it will help you.

Comment: If the classes have to inherit from `C` to get `f2()`, why have the interface? Have you also considered implementing `f2()` as an extension method, as opposed to declaring it on the interface?

Answer (score 3):

You should create just one abstract class with methods f1() and f2() as follows:

```
abstract class A
{
    public abstract f1();
    protected void f2()
    {
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public override void f1()
    {
    }
}
```

Now whenever you create an class based upon A, they can specify their own behavior for method f1().

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use a strategy pattern:

```
public interface IF1Strategy
{
   void f1();
}

public sealed class C : I1
{
    private readonly IF1Strategy _f1Strategy;

    //strategy injected
    public C(IF1Strategy strategy)
    {
       _f1Strategy = strategy;
    }

    void f2()
    {
    }

    void f1()
    {
       //delegated to strategy
       _f1Strategy.f1();
    }
}
```

NB: Only suitable if your `f1` strategy implementors do not need to call `f2`.

Advantages:

- You can inject the appropriate strategy.
- You can unit test strategies on their own.
- Class `C` can change independant of the others i.e. that saves you maintaining a class heirachy. Note how I have `sealed` it.

In short, I am choosing [Composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Answer (score 0):

I am following OOPs design principle along with strategy pattern to provide a good solution for your problem. 
these are the principle i follow:
1. Favor composition over inheritance.
2. Program to interface not implementation,

```
  public interface I1VariedBehavior
{
    void f1(); // Varies for the implementation.
}
public abstract class I1SameBehavior
{

    public void f2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("f2 same behavior");
    }
}
public class F1Impl1 : I1VariedBehavior
{
    public void f1() // f1 is own implementation 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("F1 own implementation 1");
    }
}
public class F1Impl2 : I1VariedBehavior
{
    public void f1() // f1 is own implementation 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("F1 own implementation 2");
    }
}
public class C1 : I1SameBehavior
{
    I1VariedBehavior strategy;
    public C1(I1VariedBehavior strategy)
    {
        this.strategy = strategy;
    }
    public void f1()
    {
        strategy.f1();
    }        
}

public class Client
{
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        C1 c1 = new C1(new F1Impl1());
        c1.f1();
        c1.f2();

        C1 c2 = new C1(new F1Impl2());
        c2.f1();
        c2.f2();
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

output:

```
F1 own implementation 1
f2 same behavior
F1 own implementation 2
f2 same behavior
```

hope that helps.